# Wordpress custom taxonomy, posts urls

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxanomy and posts. On my site there are categories and subcategories.

**Now URLSs look like this:**

post: domen/product/lorem-post/
category: domen/category/lorem-category/
sybcategory: domen/category/lorem-subcategory/

**It is necessary to change this structure:**

post: domen/lorem-category/lorem-post/
category: domen/lorem-category/
sybcategory: domen/lorem-category/lorem-subcategory/

**My code:**

```
function create_products() {
    register_post_type('products', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'            => __( 'Каталог', 'theme-domain' ),
            'singular_name'   => __( 'Товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'add_new'         => __( 'Добавить товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'add_new_item'    => __( 'Новый товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'edit'            => __( 'Редактировать товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'edit_item'       => __( 'Редактировать товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'new_item'        => __( 'Новый товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'all_items'       => __( 'Все товары', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'view'            => __( 'Смотреть товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'view_item'       => __( 'Смотреть товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'search_items'    => __( 'Искать товар', 'theme-domain'  ),
            'not_found'       => __( 'Товар не найден', 'theme-domain'  ),
        ),
        'public' => true, // show in admin panel?
        'menu_position' => 0,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'product',
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_products' );

add_action( 'init', 'create_products_taxonomy', 0 );
function create_products_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Категории товаров', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Категории товаров', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Поиск товара', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Все товары', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Родительская категория', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Родительская категория', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Редактировать категорию', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить категорию', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить новую категорию', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Имя новой категории', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Категории товаров', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array (
            'slug'=>'products'
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'products_tax', array( 'products' ), $args );
};
```

Comment: What where your efforts to achieve the goal?